# How to remove a div on click and show another div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show a hidden div once a user click on a text input and remove the div that was displayed, but if the user click again on the text input I don't want the div that just got deleted to show up again.

I have tried this so far:

```
<div id="div1"> Have to be remove on click</div>

<div id="div2">Hidden on page load and show on click</div>

<input type="text" id="input" placeholder="click here" />
```

.

```
$(function(){
    $("#div2").hide();
    $("#div1").show();
    $("#input").on("click", function(){

      $(" #div2").toggle();

    });

});
```

Comment: I do not think your question is clear. You want #div1 to hide and div2 to show when you click the button? After it clicks it should not reappear??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this below snippet solves your problem, please let me know if this helps you!

```js
$(function(){
    $("#div2").hide();
    $("#div1").show();
    $("#input").on("click", function(){
      $("#div1").hide();
      $(" #div2").show();
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1"> Have to be remove on click</div>

<div id="div2">Hidden on page load and show on click</div>

<input type="text" id="input" placeholder="click here" />
```

Comment: Your example it's almost working , but if the user click again on the text input  the div2 disappear. I don't want the div2 to disappear after it has show up .

Answer (score 1):

> I want to show a hidden div once a user click on a text input and
>   remove the div that was displayed

Add a `focus` event to the `input`

```
$("#input").on("focus", function() {
  $("#div1").remove(); //div1 is removed
  $(" #div2").show(); //hidden div is shown
});

$("#input").on("blur", function() {
  $(" #div2").hide(); //div2 is hidden again
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$("#input").on("focus", function() {
  $("#div1").remove(); //div1 is removed
  $(" #div2").show(); //hidden div is shown
});

$("#input").on("blur", function() {
  $(" #div2").hide(); //div2 is hidden again
});
```

```css
#div2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1"> Have to be remove on click</div>
<div id="div2">Hidden on page load and show on click</div>
<input type="text" id="input" placeholder="click here" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("#input").click(function(){
      $("#div1").toggle();
    }); 
});
```

Don't make two buttons, one for **hide** and other one for **show**.
Make one button and use **toggle()**.
Now that's all you need ... This will definitely work.

Read this it will help you 
https://www.javatpoint.com/jquery-toggle

:)